# What are the pros and cons between UIImageView and CCSprite?

Tags: xcode, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone, uiimage, ccsprite

What are the pros and cons between `UIImageView` and `CCSprite`?

I am using `UIImageView` for our app's UI using `initWithContentsOfFile:` and I am afraid that it will cause too much memory than a `CCSprite` does. Basically, when I call `removeFromSuperview`, will it unload the `UIImage` used by my `UIImageView` and frees up all the memory used by that `UIImage`?

Also, can we say `removeFromSuperview` is equal to `removeFromParentAndCleanUp:`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking the wrong question. First, it's very easy to test which uses more memory (create one or the other, check memory in Instruments). But it shouldn't really matter (much) what kind of class displays an image on the screen, because the image (texture) itself will consume most of the memory anyway. I doubt you will see a significant difference between UIImageView and CCSprite when they both display the same 512x512 image because 99% of memory usage will be the texture.

The main benefit of CCSprite is performance, specifically for realtime animations you need CCSprite. For user interfaces in menu screens the UIViews are just fine though.

In addition cocos2d caches already loaded textures. I can't say the same for UIImageView. So CCSprite will be faster if you create and dismiss sprites using the same texture frequently.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, it is just fine if I use `UIImageView` for my HUDs right? Thanks!

Comment: for HUD? Not really. For menus, yes. Depends on the game though, a turn-based game: why not? Action game: no-no.

Comment: Let's say, our is in Cocos2D, for characters and other objects. And there are buttons, and if you press a button another UI will appear. The UI will have `UIImageView` for background, `UILabel` for text and `UIButton` for action, will that be just fine?